# C++ Constructor With Parameters Won't Initialize, Errors C2059 and C2228

Tags: winforms, parameters, constructor, c++-cli

I'm a C# programmer trying to muddle through C++ to create a Windows Forms Application.
I have a Windows Form that makes use of a user-created class.  Basically I'm trying to use a constructor that takes parameters, but my form won't let me initialize the object with parameter.   Here's the code, hopefully somebody can explain the problem to me because I'm completely baffled...

Here's my header file: BankAcct.h

```
public ref class BankAcct
{
    private:
        int money;

    public:
        BankAcct();
        BankAcct(int);
        void Deposit(int);
        void GetBalance(int&);
};
```

And my definition file: BankAcct.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "BankAcct.h"

BankAcct::BankAcct()
{
    money = 0;  
}
BankAcct::BankAcct(int startAmt)
{
    money = startAmt;
}
void BankAcct::Deposit(int depAmt)
{
    money += depAmt;
}
void BankAcct::GetBalance(int& balance)
{
    balance = money;
}
```

And finally my main form.  Won't copy the whole thing, of course, but I'm trying to declare the new bank account object, and start it with a balance of say $50.

```
private:
    BankAcct myAccount(50);    //does not work!  WHY??

//private:
  //BankAcct myAccount;    //works
```

then in the form constructor my code is this:

```
public:
    frmBank(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int bal;
        myAccount.GetBalance(bal);
        lblBankBalance->Text += Convert::ToString(bal);
    }
```

I've included the BankAcct.h file at the top of my frmBank.h, what else am I doing wrong here?  It works great if I use the default constructor (the one that starts the bank balance at zero).  I get the following error messages:

error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'

and

error C2228: left of '.GetBalance' must have class/struct/union

Thank you for any and all help on this one!!

Comment: This is C++/cli right? Not C++? If you don't know the difference: [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B),  [C++/cli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)

Comment: Yes, C++/CLI.  In Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#-style initialization does not work in C++. You need to put initializers in the initialization section of your constructor (i.e. between `:` and the opening brace `{` of the constructor:

```
public:
    MyForm() : myAccount(50) {
        // Your constructor
    }
private:
    BankAcct myAccount;
```

The way you have it now, `myAccount` is not defined as `BankAcct`, so calls of `GetBalance` do not compile either.

Comment: Tried it and it worked, but I have never seen this technique of initialization before.  Do you know of any links to tutorials, explanations etc?  Or even suggest some key words to google search on?

Comment: Also, as a follow-up question: What if I want to initialize 2 (or more) bank accounts in the same form?

Comment: @SomeGirl Take a look at the [constructors section of the C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html), section 10.6. Look up "initialization lists" for more info. If you need to initialize multiple member variables, separate them by commas: `acct1(123), acct2(456)`. You need to put them in the same order in which they are declared in your class.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You're not actually required to put them in the same order as declaration, the compiler will treat it like you did. ignores The order they appear in the *ctor-initializer-list* is ignored, initialization occurs in declaration order.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the clarification. I decided to simplify the explanation, but you are certainly right.

Answer (score 0):

One easy workaround:

```
private:
    BankAcct *myAccount; // Make this a pointer
```

... then ...

```
frmBank(void)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myAccount = new BankAcct(50);
    int bal = myAccount->GetBalance(bal);
    lblBankBalance->Text += Convert::ToString(bal);
```

There are other approaches, too.  But I think explicitly creating the "myAccount" object is arguably the clearest and simplest.  IMHO...

Comment: This didn't work for me, it says the following errors:

C3699: '*' cannot use this indirection on type 'BankAcct'
C2750: 'BankAcct': cannot use 'new' on the reference type; use 'gcnew' instead
C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'BankAcct *' to 'BankAcct ^'
Along with the other errors from before.

Comment: Ah - that's because you're apparently using Microsoft's .Net dialect of C++:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Comment: Yes I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  So can I still use this workaround?    Or a similar technique?  @paul

Comment: Been experimenting with it, it works if I do BankAcct ^myAccount and then, myAccount = gcnew BankAccount(50).  Thanks for your help!